# playing music continuously in the loop

Tags: java

I have written this code for playing music, this code plays music once but I want to play it continuously in the loop please tell how I can do that?

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import sun.audio.*;

public class A {


    public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {       

        AudioPlayer MGP = AudioPlayer.player;
        AudioStream BGM = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("sounds.wav"));
        AudioPlayer.player.start(BGM);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, `start` will cause the player to:

> Start playing a stream. The stream will continue to play until the stream runs out of data, or it is stopped.

Hence, you could just wrap it in an endless loop:

```
public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {       

        AudioPlayer MGP = AudioPlayer.player;
        while(true) { 
            AudioStream BGM = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("sounds.wav"));
            AudioPlayer.player.start(BGM);
            BGM.close();
        }
    }
}
```